# Typechecking protected tagged union

Tags: c++

I have to build an expression tree and I'm doing that as follows. I have  a Tree that has a root of type `TreeNode<Token>*` where Token and TreeNode  looks like this:

```
struct Token {
    enum{
        PLUS, MINUS, NUMBER, VARIABLE, SIN, COS, POW, PRODUCT, DIVIDE, PI
    } type;

    union{

        char variable;
        double number;

    };//union

};

template <class T>
class TreeNode{

    public:

        TreeNode();
        ~TreeNode();
        TreeNode<T>* getLeft() const;
        TreeNode<T>* getRight() const;
        void setLeft(TreeNode<T>* node);
        void setRight(TreeNode<T>* node);
        void setInfo(T value);
        T getInfo() const;

    protected:
        T info;
        TreeNode<T> *left;
        TreeNode<T> *right;

};
```

My problem is that I have no idea to access the type of the Token since the info is protected. I have tried something like

```
 root->getInfo().number = cos(root->getRight()->getInfo().number);
```

(here I know the root has a right child which has the correct type etc so this should be okay) but this gets me the following error:

```
error: using temporary as lvalue [-fpermissive]
```

Please help!

Comment: `getInfo` returns a temporary, so assigning to its `.number` is not what you want. You need to be calling `setInfo()` and passing in a new `Token`

Comment: @AndyG Perfect! if you post this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for `TreeNode<T>::getInfo` returns `T` which is a temporary. You don't want to attempt to assign to it, because that will have no effect.

Instead, call `TreeNode<T>::setInfo` to replace your underlying `Token` with the one you desire.